# I can't import mock in my eclipse pydev

Tags: python, mocking, pydev

I download mock1.0.1 from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock.
I installed it 'python setup.py install' ok.
I test the mock in Command line is worked well.
But when I used it in eclipse like this "from mock import Mock" it report error"Unresolved import: Mock Unused import: Mock"

I changed the low version mock0.8.0 is all the same.

what's wrong?

my environment:
win7
eclipse 3.7 
ptthon 2.7.3 
mock1.0.1

Comment: try adding `#@UnresolvedImport` to your import declaration; it should clear up your errors. In my experience with pydev it may not recognize imports as valid even when python will find them perfectly. Note that if python in fact cannot find the imports you will get an error at runtime.

Comment: when I run the code import the mock in eclipse, it's not error. But it's just show the red fork in the code view.